# How to Block Clipboard Copy & paste in Linux GUI

Tags: clipboard

As admin i want to block the clipboard access in Linux GUI. No user can copy data from terminal or other thing.
In simple terms it means just **block** the copy option.

Answer (score 1):

I don't expect you'd be be able to easily disable the X selection mechanism, but you could start a process that connects to every X server that steals the selections (and empty the `CUT_BUFFER0`) every time a process tries to own them. Here using `xclip` and `xprop` utilities, though you'd probably want to write a program that does the equivalent to make it more lightweight (especially if using a clipboard manager that would try and constantly steal back the CLIPBOARD selection off you).

Like:

```
for sel in clipboard primary secondary; do
  while xclip -i -sel "$sel" -q; do
    xprop -root -format CUT_BUFFER0 8s -set CUT_BUFFER0 ''
  done &
done <> /dev/null >&0 2>&0
```

Comment: for steals the selection for Admin it's not a big deal . there are lots of tools available to check it out.

Comment: i want genuine method to stop the copy & paste method